# R Shiny: is there a way to execute HTML through DashboardPagePlus?

Tags: html, r, shiny

Hi all I am new to UI programming and even newer to R shiny.

I have a Shiny UI defined as:

```
         ....
ui <- shinyUI(
           dashboardPagePlus(
         ....
        )
)
```

All I want to do is execute some html to set the title of my tab in the web browser. I have tried using a fluid page object to return a title but dashboardPagePlus doesn't seem to like it that much and some other things I've tried include:

```
tags$head(HTML("<title>My Tab</title>"))
```

but it seems to go ignored by the interpreter. Any insight or resources are greatly appreciated.

```
tags$title("My Tab")
```

crashes the program

```
     ....
ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(title = "My Tab"),
  dashboardPagePlus(
     ....
    )
)
```

also crashes the program

Edit: picture for clarity
[what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjQCe.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjQCe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use HTML in order to create a title (unless you want to do some custom formatting).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)


#####/UI/####

header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  title = "My Tab"
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(title="Browser title", header, sidebar, body, rightsidebar)

#####/SERVER/####

server <- function(session, input, output) { 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: not exactly, I'm trying to change the tab text in the browser not the tab in the dashboard, I'll update my question for clarity. Thank you for your input however

Comment: added a picture

Comment: this has the desired effect I was after so I'm going to accept it, but do you know why when I add ```title = "Browser Title",``` I receive the error  ```argument is not interpretable as logical```